# How do I create a model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some difficulties properly understanding laravel models. Let's take the default model provided by the framework as an example.

This is the whole content of the Model:

**User.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

I understand everything that happens between `{}`. But there are things I'm totally lost:

Like, how to set this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
```

Do I need that if I'm creating a model to let's say the table `products` instead of the table `users`? And which ones do I need to `use` if the table is other rather than a user table and doesn't require authentication? Am I also not understanding properly the authentication?

Plus, there is another one:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
```

I know I have to extend eloquent class in order to interact with the database, but same question regarding the implements: **Do I need them for a no-users table? Do I need a different ones ?**

Thank you for all the help you guys can provide me and if I didn't make myself clear enough or you just have any doubt, something else you want to know from me, don't hesitate to ask me. I'm really looking forward to have a well rounded comprehension of models in laravel before going further in the project I'm working now and getting stuck due to a lack of basic concepts regarding the technology that I'm using rather than due to the common technical difficulty that working in programming has. Learning the hard way just means that you didn't get the right approach while learning. I've been bitten by that dog several times.

Answer (score 19):

You can use artisan to create a model like this:

```
php artisan make:model YourNewModel
```

Answer (score 3):

Furthermore, if you wanted to make a model, controller, and migration. you can do:

```
php artisan make:model YourNewModel -mcr
```

php artisan will create basic CRUD controller and the model, was well as the migration. All the stock dependancies will be created as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want create model then run this artisan command

> php artisan make:model YourModelName

If you want to create model, migration and controller then run this artisan command.

> php artisan make:model YourModelName -mcr

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need this, if you are creating products model :

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
```

You should use something like this:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

     protected $table = 'products';

     public $timestamps = false;

     protected $softDelete = false;

}
```

Check this link about models: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

I would recommend doing some of step by step laravel tutorials. It will answer most of your questions . Laracast https://laracasts.com/ have some really amazing video tutorials. Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: So I was right: if I'm not modelling a users table I don't need then neither the included files at the top nor the implementation in the class declaration right?

Comment: @DaseinA Yes, but still my advice is to check some Laravel tutorial, then you will understand when to use these interfaces and when not. We could tell you here the answer, Yes and No, but you need to understand when it should be used(interfaces).

Comment: I'd rather wait for an answer that summarizes the concept of models in Laravel rather than an answer that just recommnds me to study Laravel. If you read the last paragraph of my question you will notice that. Or just the fact that I have made the question could be the clue. Yet, I appeciate your intentions.

Comment: hi @user2755140, if you are waiting for an answer that summarize the concept of models, you will need to read [the basics of MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309685/understanding-the-mvc-pattern). There are tons of article and SOF question regarding MVC.