# How to get data in database

Tags: php, laravel-6

Hi am new to laravel and i want to achieve the following

- I have 2 tables below namely table1 and table2

```
table1 = students[{id="1", firstname="john", lastname="doe"},
                  {id="2", firstname="james", lastname="bond"}]
```

```
table2 = subjects[{id="1", code="math101", subject="math", description="Introduction", units="3"},
                   id="2", code="eng101", subject="English", description="introduction", units="3"]
```

- now in laravel controller i want to achieve the following

```
public function create(){
 //lets assume that i received these id's from the routes
 // i want to use this id's to filter the data i want to add to the table3
  id = 2 //students
  id = 1 //subjects

table3 = enroll[{id="1" student_id="2", firstname="john", lastname="doe", code="math101", subject="math", description="Introduction", units="3"}]
```

I want to combine the data from this 2 tables and save it to the new table so it will be like in table3 above

how can i achieve this in the laravel controller

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to utilize Eloquent ORM in the Laraval framework to achive this. First of all you need to create models for each of the table in your database using the `artisan` command line and then you can do the database queries using the ORM.

You can have more information on creating Models in the laraval in the following thread.

[How do I create a model in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709143/how-do-i-create-a-model-in-laravel)

And then you can do the queries as per the eloquent documentation inside in the controllers.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent